# How to ensure pod is starting even if a older version of the same pod was running

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod used as initContainers for other pods. Whenever, the new deployment is happening the existing initContainers still continues to run. How to ensure the deployment not picking up the old pod even if no changes made to that pod. For each deployment it should create a newer version of the pod which was configured as initContainers.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how initContainers work. They apply only to whatever PodSpec they are defined in and have no impact on any other pods.

Comment: In that case, how we can achive the same with normal pod. I mean the deployment should start a fresh pod even if no chages made to the existing running pod.

Comment: Hi, If those answers above doesn't explain how [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers) works, please provide more details - what is your current stage what is desired state in your example

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how initContainers work -- but from context that this "I have a pod used as initContainers for other pods" is talking about a container image, not a pod.

Based on that guess, you could be talking about a number of different things.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: whatever
...
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

By default, a deployment will create a new pod first, and then terminate the old one.  Recreate changes that and terminates the old pod before starting to create it's replacement.

```
...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
    ...
      containers:
      - image: some.registry/image:tag
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

pull policy is usually Always, IfNotPresent (but can, for offline clusters, also be "Never").

This will determine whether your pod will pull an updated copy of the container image from your registry before use.

Based on your other reply:

> I mean the deployment should start a fresh pod even if no changes made
> to the existing running pod.

```
kubectl -n namespace rollout restart deploy/whatever
```

I think you're talking about container images, not pods.  In which case if you have a "IfNotPresent" pull policy and for some reason do not want to update it to "Always", the hackery option for a small cluster is to run "crictl pull ..." on each worker node, and then rollout restart.

hth